# Accessing email content in outlook web addin

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am writing a addin that requires the email content in MIME format. Now I am using the `ewsurl()`, `getCallBackTokenAsync()`, and `Office.context.mailbox.itemId` api's to find out the EWS url, access token, message id and sending it to my back-end via Ajax. My back-end sends a SOAP request to EWS and downloads the email message. Is this approach correct?

My main concern is will there be any throttling if the EWS endpoint sees too many request coming from the same machine. For example, several users(say couple of hundreds) in an organisation  could use the add-in concurrently. In this case , the add-in back-end could send several concurrent requests to EWS. Would EWS implement some throttling if it sees too many requests coming from the same add-in / the same back-end machine

Are there any alternative approaches?

Answer (score 0):

This is the only approach at the moment. Neither Office.js nor Graph supports getting the raw email message. Given that add-ins run within the context of a single email, I can't imagine this would result in more than a couple of calls per second at most so I wouldn't be too concerned with throttling.

Comment: Thanks Marc. To clarify my question further, if several users(say couple of  hundreds) in an organization use the add-in concurrently. In this case , the add-in backend could send several concurrent requests to EWS. Would the EWS implement some throttling if it sees too many requests coming from the same add-in / the same backend machine.

Answer (score 0):

> I am writing a addin that requires the email content in MIME format.

You will **not** be able to get **original MIME message**. Exchange doesn't store MIME content. You may get generated MIME content which done on the fly by Exchange and this conversion is expensive. Resieved MIME message has nothing to do with original MIME received by Exchange, so why bother? The maximum you will be able to get with EWS requests is original message headers (`PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS`), but not entire original MIME message.

Limits: If you would use EWS requests from the client (`makeEwsRequestAsync` ) you would be limited to 3 asynchronous calls and 1 Mb of response. If you do this from your server you will be able by pass those limits. More on this: [Limits for activation and JavaScript API for Outlook add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/limits-for-activation-and-javascript-api-for-outlook-add-ins)

Comment: Thanks Slava for the link. That was useful. By "email content in MIME format", i meant the value of <t:MimeContent> section  that we get in response to GetItem  EWS call.

Comment: @BalakrishnanRajkumar I have modified my answer to clarify my point. What I refer to was "original MIME" which travels through Internet. This original MIME cannot be retrieved as Exchange doesn't keep it. Instead by your request you will receive generated by Exchange MIME content, which has nothing to do with original MIME. It will/may use different encoding, boundaries, etc. And this is considered expensive Exchange operation.